# while running mysql -u root got ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: 18.04

while running the following code :
**mysql -u root**
i got the error,"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> using password: NO

Provide the password it wants. The line you should be using is

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and it will then ask for the password for mysqluser `root`.