# Can't run mysql commands as root linux user

Tags: mysql, sudo, root

As linux root user:

`root@local:~# mysql`

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I'm confused. Shouldn't the root user be able to run `mysql` without additional authentication? How do I fix this?

(Environment details: fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install, mysql installed with apt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [while running mysql -u root got ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269936/while-running-mysql-u-root-got-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-root)

Comment: This is a common mistake. User 'root' for mysql is not user 'root' for Ubuntu.  You have to define a specific password for mysql user 'root'.  See eg this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/237362/mysql-access-denied-for-user-root-while-using-lamp/254654#254654

Comment: I'm not specifying a mysql user. I just want to run mysql commands as sudo/root. Lots of applications, i.e. running commands in an install script

Comment: Provide the password you setup mysql's user "root" with. If not you don't have a root user in mysql. root mysql != root Ubuntu "Shouldn't the root user be able to run mysql without additional authentication?" UNLESS you set it up with a password.

Comment: Installing MySQL on Ubuntu will require a password for the root user. Since a while ago, you can't have a passwordless root account by default in MySQL. During the package installation, you must have been asked to input a password.